# stop images from being downloaded on webpage in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, internet, images, google-chrome-extensions

I am on a limited connection. I would like to be able to stop chrome from downloading images (not hiding images) on webpages. I would also prefer any alternative browser as solution if this feature is not available for chrome.

There is an option in Chrome to disable showing images, however according to https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/HQvNLtAg3SQ it does not prevent images from loading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this in Firefox. If you browser to `about:config` and set the `permissions.default.image` option to 2 it will stop loading images. See http://kb.mozillazine.org/Permissions.default.image

Answer (score 8):

Go to: chrome://settings/

Show advanced settings

Content settings

Under images select Do not show any images

Comment: are you sure if it disables image download because i am referring to stopping image download not turning off display of images?

Comment: @Suhan if this does not disable the download the what you want is simply not possible

Comment: How can you do that? HTTP sends a request to the remote server for a webpage. it returns your request. Im not sure how to stop this...

Comment: Opera Turbo is a feature of the Opera web browser might be good. In my experience it helps save bandwidth a lot! http://www.opera.com/turbo

Comment: HTTP sends request for A PAGE, which is just HTML text; it's up to the browser to decide what to do with image URLS.

Comment: It's working well, you can see Chrome did not send any request to get image in DevTools under Network tab.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good extension for Chrome:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/text-mode/adelhekhakakocomdfejiipdnaadiiib

It replaces un-donwloaded images by a customizable pattern, rather than "deleting" images and messing up page structure. Unfortunately I was not yet able to find an extension which shows ALT tag texts in place of the images... which is weird, being the ALT tag there just for this reason!!

Other 4 extension I tested are not good: some keep downloading images but they don't show them (???), others do not work at all, others block images for ALL pages, while this one does it only upon specifically activating the extension for each page.

edit:
QuickBlock also shows ALT TEXT:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/quickblock/jlkpnekpomdbobkdokohimfcbgcpldfp?hl=en

Comment: this extension "Text Mode" is funny, it makes pictures B/W, and it seems to always let some images come thru (I made it sure by typing random words at google image search). Still, it seems to help on lowering data usage (like when we need to use cellphone internet connection on PC). But I am still looking for the perfect alternative that lets me see only chosen images in place (not in a new tab), that show the alt text as you said, and that actually really block all images.

Comment: the b/w effect is to inform you that extension is enabled. What do you mean by "lets me see only chosen images in place (not in a new tab)" ?

Comment: Found (and added to answer) QuickBlock: it shows ALT TEXT.

Comment: QuickBlock seems the best solution in case we need to use cellphone connection on the computer, thx!!

Answer (score 0):

I just found a working extension and installed on chromium! "Block Image"
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/block-image/pehaalcefcjfccdpbckoablngfkfgfgj
It only has On/Off, but is saving my 100MB quota!

udpate: now using "HTML content blocker" from this tip https://superuser.com/a/1122390/157532

---

also,
as the accepted answer was about FireFox and not Chrome (therefore I think the OP subject could be changed)

I would like to add this alternative to **Linux**:
I've been using **konqueror** most of the time, I just open chromium if I need something specific that works better there.

here the adblock cfg I use that you can import on konqueror:

```
[AdBlock]
http://*.bmp
http://*.flash
http://*.gif
http://*.jpg
http://*.png
https://*.bmp
https://*.flash
https://*.gif
https://*.jpg
https://*.png
https://*.googleusercontent.com/*
https://encrypted-tbn*.gstatic.com/*
https://graph.facebook.com/*
```

the last 3 are meant to block images that come w/o explicit extension, have fun adding others :)

if you need to see images once, just keep the settings popup opened and enable/disable the adblock checkbox, quite practical.

Comment: beware when using konqueror config hotkeys! alt+D will clean that list, good I had this online backup...