# How to block any type of video from loading/playing online (YouTube, Netflix, Vimeo etc) in all browsers

Tags: windows, windows-8, google-chrome, browser

I am currently trying to beat my addiction to spending countless hours online watching YouTube videos etc. The issue I am currently facing is that I need YouTube for my daily work(Reading and replying to comments, researching channels, etc), but I get too distracted by all the videos on the sites. Is there any way to deactivate any type of video loading for all browsers?

Is there something similar to editing the host file in Windows?

The perfect solution would be something that does not involve chrome, firefox, opera, etc. extensions, as those are extremely easy to delete (Yes, I am quite addicted to these sites...)

Comment: You want to disable video but keep YouTube ??

Comment: Adjust your firewall settings to block traffic from those sites. You can either do this on Windows, or possibly from your router.

Comment: @harrymc Yes, precisely. I want YouTube to function as always, except that the videos would not load. Basically that I would not be able to watch the videos, but interact with YouTube as per usual

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1038968/how-to-block-disable-all-videos-from-automatically-loading-in-chrome